# Can I use the same Objectify instance in multiple servlets?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, objectify

I am using Objectify in my GAE application and I have multiple servlets that make use of Objectify. Can I use the same instance of an Objectify object in all these servlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never share an Objectify object instance between threads.  You should create an Objectify, use it in your request, and throw it away at the end.  Or even create multiple instances within a request; they are cheap.

Comment: Generally servlets are multithreaded; many requests will execute on the same servlet object.